# Regex to find `$this->request->data['utility_location_id']`

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to match the following string:

`$this->request->data['utility_location_id']`

Tried:

```
[[$]this[-][>]request[-][>]data[\[\'](\w{0,22})[\'\]]
```

Replace with: `$this->request->getData\((\1)\)`

Returns: `$this->request->getData()utility_location_id']`

What I want: `$this->request->getData('utility_location_id')`

However : 
The following one :

FInd : 
`[[$]this[-][>]request[-][>]data[\[\'](.*)[\'\]]`

Replace : `$this->request->getData\((\1)\)`

Output : `$this->request->getData('utility_location_id')`

But it also matches the following string :

```
$this->request->data['utility_location_id']adasdadasd->datas  sad  sada ['utility_location_id']
```

which is a problem . How to fix it ? 
I know it is for (.*) .

Comment: No. Sorry for wrong return . Please check now edited.

Comment: Try "Find" `(\$this->request->)data\[('.*?')]` and "Replace" with `$1getData\($2\)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[\[\']` is a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), so it will match only one character. You should use `[\[']+` instead or better just `\['`. Same story for `[\'\]]`.

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/lzUHVD/1)

Remember to use `(?:X)` instead of `[X]` for [non-capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: Link only answer is useless.

Comment: @Toto I answered to the question about the specific case and added 1 link for testing and 2 links for further reading. The OP did not seem to consider this useless.

Comment: Considere future readers, and may be the link will be break. The minimum required is to show the regex instead of talking about non capture groups that are not used here.

Comment: @Toto I supposed the OP used the wrapping `[...]` in the first regex as non-capturing group, therefore I corrected it. My reply answers to the question (even without considering the links) because it indicates where the error is and how to correct it. Anyway, you can post a better answer, if you wish to.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need below code .....
Find what: `data\K\[(.*?id')\]`
Replace with: `($1)` or `(\1)`